# Repeated data when rank() in sql bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm creating a table from a dataset that have columns the top N in several areas and separated in two categories b a flag.

The query I use for this is the following:

```
WITH ranking as (
      SELECT  order, name, id, area, flag,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY area, flag ORDER BY orders DESC) as rank
      FROM `dataset` d
    ) 

SELECT area, current_date() as date,
case when rank = 1 then CONCAT(id,'_', name) end as top_1_in_the_city,
case when rank = 2 then CONCAT(id,'_', name) end as top_2_in_the_city,
case when rank = 3 then CONCAT(id,'_', name) end as top_3_in_the_city,


case when rank = 1 AND flag = 0 then CONCAT(id,'_', name) end as top_1_in_the_city_core,
case when rank = 2 AND flag = 0 then CONCAT(id,'_', name) end as top_2_in_the_city_core,
case when rank = 3 AND flag = 0 then CONCAT(id,'_', name) end as top_3_in_the_city_core,

case when rank = 1 AND flag = 1 then CONCAT(id,'_', name) end as top_1_in_the_city_nocore,
case when rank = 2 AND flag = 1 then CONCAT(id,'_', name) end as top_2_in_the_city_nocore,
case when rank = 3 AND flag = 1 then CONCAT(id,'_', name) end as top_3_in_the_city_nocore,
FROM ranking
```

But it returns a lot of null and some names, that before only appeared once, now appears in several tops, and of course it can't be top 1 and top 4 at the same time, like this:

```
date area  top_1_in_the_city top_2_in_the_city top_1_in_the_city_core
05/05/1989      null             James              null
05/05/1989      James            null               null 
05/05/1989      null             null               null
```

The expected result  was:

```
date area  top_1_in_the_city   top_2_in_the_city   top_1_in_the_city_core top_1_in_the_city_nocore
05/05/1989      Pedro             James              James               Pedro
05/05/1989      Arthur             Don                Arthur            Michael
05/05/1989      Fulano             John               John              Someone
```

To fix this I tried first the simplest case without the flag, but had the same issue. Then I tried to coalesce each case, but it stayed exactly the same! Thanks in advance

Comment: . . I would suggest that you delete this question.  Ask a NEW question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  The results make perfect sense to me.  I just have no idea what you are trying to do -- hence, no basis for answering the question.

Comment: "a table from a dataset that have columns the top N in several areas and separated in two categories by a flag"

Comment: Your results display a column `date` but there is no mention of `date` in the displayed query. I suspect that if you show the full query it may become apparent what the problem is.

Comment: Its addead as "current_date() as date", is it wrong like this?

Comment: And I'll throw in that the results  have five columns but the query returns 11 columns.  I stick with my original advice.

Comment: Isn't it obvius that the missing columns are like the 3 presented but repeated? The only missing one with "useful" info would be area. What original advice? Do you realize you're in a different question that the one you answered? Is a new question, with sample data, desired results and an explanation

Comment: @AaronG., can you provide the sample of the source data? So I can perform some tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a wild stab because your question is missing quite a bit of explanation.  There are 2 main issues with your query if you are trying to do what I think you are doing.

1. You are trying to use the same rank in 2 different contexts.  It will be easier to add a 2nd rank variable.
2. Your query isn't limiting rows, so you are likely getting a result for every single row of your table.  I'm guessing you are wanting 1 row per area in this case.

If my interpretation of your query is anywhere close to correct, I would refactor your query into something like this:

```
with 
ranking as (
      SELECT  orders, name, id, area, flag, CONCAT(id,'_', name) as formatted_name,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY area ORDER by orders DESC) as area_rank,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY area, flag ORDER BY orders DESC) as area_flag_rank
      FROM `dataset.table` d
),
area_spine as (select distinct area from ranking),
city1 as ( select area, formatted_name as top_1_in_the_city from ranking where area_rank = 1 ),
city2 as ( select area, formatted_name as top_2_in_the_city from ranking where area_rank = 2 ),
city3 as ( select area, formatted_name as top_3_in_the_city from ranking where area_rank = 3 ),
city_core1 as ( select area, formatted_name as top_1_in_the_city_core from ranking where area_flag_rank = 1 and flag = 0),
city_core2 as ( select area, formatted_name as top_2_in_the_city_core from ranking where area_flag_rank = 2 and flag = 0 ),
city_core3 as ( select area, formatted_name as top_3_in_the_city_core from ranking where area_flag_rank = 3 and flag = 0 ),
city_nocore1 as ( select area, formatted_name as top_1_in_the_city_nocore from ranking where area_flag_rank = 1 and flag = 1),
city_nocore2 as ( select area, formatted_name as top_2_in_the_city_nocore from ranking where area_flag_rank = 2 and flag = 1),
city_nocore3 as ( select area, formatted_name as top_3_in_the_city_nocore from ranking where area_flag_rank = 3 and flag = 1),
joined as (
  select *
  from area_spine
  left join city1 using(area)
  left join city2 using(area)
  left join city3 using(area)
  left join city_core1 using(area)
  left join city_core2 using(area)
  left join city_core3 using(area)
  left join city_nocore1 using(area)
  left join city_nocore2 using(area)
  left join city_nocore3 using(area)
)
select * from joined
```